# Holding an array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays

I am trying to create a database with a table called `MEETING`.

So every instance of a `meeting`, just like real life can contain a variable amount of people in it.

So `meeting1` (inside **MEETING**) may contain `user1`, `user2`, `user3`.

but `meetings2` (again inside **MEETING**) may contain `user1`, `user4`, `user6`, `user7`.

How would I go about handling such a scenario. I was thinking of creating an array, but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use what is called a join table. You would have three tables: MEETING, USER, and the join table (it could be called MEETING_USER or something like that). Your user table would contain information about each user (at the very least, some identifier and a username). Each meeting would also have a unique ID as well. Your join table would then have rows in the format ,  with a new entry for each user at a meeting. This facilitates what is called a many-to-many relation since each meeting can have many users and each user can attend many meetings.

Some sql engines in MySQL allow you to add "foreign key mappings" so that it runs pretty fast when searching for all users in a meeting or all meetings a user has attended. Other database servers (MSSQL, etc) also support this kind of thing.

Example:

- Meeting 1 has id 123
- Meeting 2 has id 345
- User 1 has id 3
- User 2 has id 4
- User 3 has id 5

If Meeting 1 was attended by users 1 and 3, the join table would have the following entries in it somewhere:

- 123, 3 (meeting 1, user 1)
- 123, 5 (meeting 1, user 3)

If Meeting 2 was attended by everyone, the join table would have these entries put in it:

- 345, 3 (meeting 2, user 1)
- 345, 4 (meeting 2, user 2)
- 345, 5 (meeting 3, user 3)

Comment: so each MEETING will have another table to go with it?

Comment: No, each meeting has an entry in the MEETING table and each user an an entry in the user table. Attendance to the meetings by users creates entries in the meeting_user table.

Comment: Well, when you create a meeting you do INSERT INTO MEETING (name) VALUES ("meeting1"). Then, you use a function to get the last inserted id (php has one, as I assume other languages do for their mysql wrappers). A similar command is used to create a user. When a user attends a meeting you run INSERT INTO MEETING_USER (meetingId, userId) VALUES (<meeting id>, <user id>). To see who attended a meeting you do SELECT * FROM USER WHERE MEETING_USER.meetingId = <meeting id> AND MEETING_USER.userId = USER.id. This assumes you have a column named id in the MEETING table and USER table.

Comment: Also, pluralizing the table names would probably be good since the MEETING table holds meetings and your USER table holds users (note the s at the end). You would then call your tables MEETINGS  and USERS.